# Is there a way to use ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot and exclude specific gameobject oui from the captured screen in runtime?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class HiResScreenshots : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int resWidth = 1920;
    public int resHeight = 1080;
    public SaveLoad saveLoad;

    public static string ScreenShotName(int width, int height)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/Saved Screenshots/screen_{1}x{2}_{3}.png",
                             Application.dataPath,
                             width, height,
                             System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
        {
            var filename = ScreenShotName(resWidth, resHeight);
            var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(filename);

            string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) + ".savegame.txt";

            StartCoroutine(saveLoad.SaveWithTime(directory,Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) + ".savegame.txt"));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pressing the K key once and it's taking a screenshot of the game view window and save it as png to the hard drive.

For example :

[image: Example]

Let's say I want to exclude from the captured screen the left ui element or maybe only to exclude the cube or maybe to exclude both from the captured screen.

The idea to make some kind of List of objects mixed with ui's that I will not want to be in the saved screenshot/s.

Comment: Did you consider making a separate camera for this, using its visible layers mask to exclude unwanted objects? Then you can capture that camera's view to a RenderTexture.

Comment: @DMGregory I tried let' say I leave the main camera as it is by default the user will keep see everything in editor and in runtime. Now the problem is that the left element in the screenshot in my question is a canvas and now it's set to Screen Space - Overlay.  I added another new camera and changed the canvas to Screen Space - Camera and dragged the new Camera to the place in the canvas. Now only the Canvas the element on the left is gone. but I don't want it to be gone  and now I can't make that the main camera will show everything. because the new camera is assigned to the canvas.

Comment: So either the main camera will display if I set now the depth to 1 but it will show only the cube and if I set back the main camera depth to -1 then it will show only the ui element canvas but not the cube. so now I can decide what object to display but cant display them both.

Comment: because I must assign the new camera to the canvas to be able to display only the cube without the cnavas using tender texture now the main camera that should show everything never will be in the front because the new camera is in the canvas Screen Space Camera.  So I'm not sure how to do it because the Save Slots in my question screenshot is a Canvas. I'm stuck here.